# Do some actions only when current location is acquired

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am designing the map-based app and I want to do certain set of steps when user's location has been acquired (blue dot has been shown on the map). On some of the devices it may take up to 1 min due to location services ramp-up process.. So the question is how do I know when Android Map managed to acquire my location, so I can start doing the rest of initialisation process?

I was thinking about implementing my own `LocationListener` and trigger callback when I receive location, but this solution seems worthless since I need to only know the point when current location has been acquired and blue dot has been shown. I don't care about location updates.

Comment: @Ty221 As I said, I tried to implement `LocationListener`, but there is too much hassle just for getting first up-to-date location. I am looking for some other ways to implement just my use-case

Comment: Ok, sorry. I canceled my downvote and deleted my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the blue dot on a map, I suppose you add the `MyLocationOverlay` to your map. If it is so, there is an easy way to do what you want - `MyLocationOverlay` has `runOnFirstFix(Rannable)` interface, so provided `Runnable` will be run as soon as the map acquires your current location:

```
this.currentLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do your magic here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just tried that - works great! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!